# Ubuntu 16 04 device descriptor read/64 error 110

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade

```
Ubuntu 16 04 device descriptor read/64 error 110
login:
```

After an upgrade to 16.04, this is what I get when starting up.  This is a dual boot system and win 8 starts fine but I cannot get past this on Ubuntu. At the beginning of the start up I get a message that it failed to load the kernel modules.

I'm new to Ubuntu. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 of 2 scenarios here.

1. either you have a broken kernel module that's trying to load at boot time
2. you have **secure boot** enabled in your BIOS and you've added a kernel module (via DKMS, or otherwise)

It's easiest to fix #2 first. Try turning off **secure boot** in your BIOS and see if that fixes the problem.

Report back.

ps: remember that in a Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot system, you'll want to turn off `fast start` in the power control panel, and turn off hibernation with `powercfg /h off` in an elevated command prompt window.

Comment: I did as you suggested with no positive results.  I did put an ISO on a flash drive and can boot to that but I can not find my files to extract and save.  If I can do that I am fine with wiping my OS

Comment: When you disabled secure boot in the BIOS and rebooted, did you continue to get BOTH error messages... one about device descriptor read error... a second one about fail to load kernel modules? Next test... remove ALL external USB/etc devices from the computer and try and boot again. If that doesn't work, try booting in recovery mode. It's important to give me PRECISE results to these tests/questions, or I'll go down a wrong path. Report back.

Comment: ps: Can you boot in recovery mode? Can you login at the login: prompt? Are you able to catch the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`? Do the UUID's shown in blkid match the UUID's in fstab?

Comment: I was able to boot to my flash drive and after a little poking around I found my files and copied them to a seperate flash drive. I then wiped the hard drive and did a fresh install and it works as expected now.

Comment: Great news! Thanks for the update. No more failed to load kernel modules, no more device descriptor errors? Keep an eye out for the kernel modules error, because as you add back drivers, it may pop up again.